# Timespan in Java and SQL?

Tags: java, mysql, time, duration

I want to save time intervals in my SQL table but I'm not sure what type to use in Java for this.

What I need to store are durations like `12:33:57` or just minutes and seconds like `02:19`. Any ideas what type I could use for java and for sql? I don't really need to make any calculations with these values, but I would like to generate charts later on, with the lengths of the mesured times.

Comment: Time intervals within the same day or across different days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mysql type you want is [`TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html), ie:

```
create table mytable (
  ...
  my_interval TIME,
  ...
);
```

If you read such columns in via JDBC, you'll get a [`java.sql.Time`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) object, which is actually a [`java.util.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) with only the time portion set (ie a time on `1970-01-01`)

Answer (score 0):

You could store the durations as seconds (or milliseconds) in an int field in Java and in an integer column in SQL (e.g. 5 minutes and 12 seconds would be stored as 312).

The Java int field could be easily converted to any format necessary for your charts (if int isn't already the best format).